# What is a{sv}(oayays)b dbus signature

Tags: systemd, d-bus, ipc

I'm trying to invoke `CreateItem` method on `org.freedesktop.secrets` dbus service.

```
busctl --user call org.freedesktop.secrets /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection CreateItem "a{sv}(oayays)b"
```

How can I figure out what kind of arguments to pass for `a{sv}(oayays)b` signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `a{sv}` dictionary with keys being strings and values variants
- `(oayays)` struct of object path (`o`), two bytearrays (`ay`) and a string (`s`)
- `b` boolean

Check the [Secrets API Specification](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/secret-storage-spec/secrets-api-0.1.html#eggdbus-method-org.freedesktop.Secrets.Collection.CreateItem) for more details about the parameters for `CreateItem`.